# Getting a happy face to show up in Java

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm having trouble with displaying my image file, src/happyFace.gif, in my Java GUI. The goal is to display an image of a smiling face that seems to glide across the program window at an angle, bouncing off of the window edges.

I think my problem is with the image variable (type ImageIcon) in src/ReboundPanel.java, because the ImageIcon class might not be compatible with future swing releases (according to Oracle's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). If this is true, I think the ImageIcon class might not be able to be supported by the swing library. I don't know how to check my swing library for this.

src/happyFace.gif

[image]

My Output Window

[image]

src/Rebound.java:

```
//********************************************************************
// Rebound.java Java Foundations
//********************************************************************
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Rebound{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Displays the main frame of the program.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rebound");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

src/ReboundPanel.java:

```
//********************************************************************
// ReboundPanel.java Java Foundations
//
// Represents the primary panel for the Rebound program.
//********************************************************************
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel{
    private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 100;
    private final int DELAY = 20, IMAGE_SIZE = 35;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private Timer timer;
    private int x, y, moveX, moveY;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the panel, including the timer for the animation.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public ReboundPanel(){
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());
        image = new ImageIcon ("happyFace.gif");
        x = 0;
        y = 40;
        moveX = moveY = 3;
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground (Color.black);
        timer.start();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Draws the image in the current location.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void paintComponent (Graphics page){
        super.paintComponent (page);
        image.paintIcon (this, page, x, y);
    }
    //*****************************************************************
    // Represents the action listener for the timer.
    //*****************************************************************
    private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener{
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        // Updates the position of the image and possibly the direction
        // of movement whenever the timer fires an action event.
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
            x += moveX;
            y += moveY;
            if (x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
                moveX = moveX * -1;
            if (y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
                moveY = moveY * -1;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I think my problem is_", and what is it exactly ? Please see [ask] then [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: can you specify your problem please. Is the Icon not even shown or is something with the animation / interaction broken?

Comment: oh sorry, the icon is not even shown. I'll add a screenshot with my current window

Comment: I don't know how to display pictures, but the screenshot is linked in "My Output Window". I also elaborated on what I think the problem is.

Comment: `image = new ImageIcon ("happyFace.gif");` The `String` argument is treated as a path to a `File` object. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: *"the ImageIcon class might not be compatible"* That's because it was not made to be **serialized** and that warning has always been there for most Swing components (I can't think of one that does not have the warning). I tried the source with a valid URL (i.e. `image = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHARa.png"));`) and it works just fine. **The problem is the image path.**

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't figure out how to upvote comments but I eventually did get the smiley to show up with the URL object.

Comment: Tip: Add @AxelH (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"I eventually did get the smiley to show up with the URL object."* Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ReboundPanel` class,

change `image = new ImageIcon("happyFace.gif");`

to `image = new ImageIcon("src/happyFace.gif");`

[image]

Note that this kind of solution should only be used for testing purposes. As stated in [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)'s comment, the correct way to store and load the image is using an [embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).